# How to reopen question incorrectly closed as a duplicate

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I've asked a [question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/61023/moving-ecommerce-products-from-one-domain-to-another) that has been incorrectly marked as a duplicate - is there anything I can do to have it reopened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other question is certainly not a duplicate, so I have re-opened.

I'm sure that a question about moving pages between domains has been asked here before.  If so, hopefully it can be marked duplicate of something appropriate.

Comment: I'm specifically moving product pages between sites - I guess that's no different to moving general pages between sites. I'll do some searching along those lines.. Thanks.